# Can we set only a specific type of user as a foreign key in a model's field

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model called CustomUser which holds two types of user, teachers and students. The model has a regd_as field which stores the type of user. The model looks as follows:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    REGD_AS_CHOICES = (
        ('TCH', 'TEACHER'),
        ('STU', 'STUDENT'),
    )
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, editable = False, default = uuid.uuid4)
    
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    
    regd_as = models.CharField(max_length= 10, choices= REGD_AS_CHOICES, null=True)
    
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.Boolea
```

Now I want to have a model that would store a referal code generated only for users who are teachers. The model looks as follows:

```py
class ReferalCode(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    
    teacher_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='teacher_user_referal', null=True)
    
    referal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
```

### Question

Is there a way to set only teachers from the **CustomUser** model as the foreignkey to teacher_user directly?

Currently I am using signals to store only teachers as the user in ReferalCode model.